# Load JavaScript on demand

Tags: javascript, load

I am using jQuery and jQuery mobile.

I think both libraries got downloaded to my iPhone over ATT's internet, which is slow.

So I am wondering if there is some framework taking care of it and trimming the file to necessary size for functions I use in the page?

Is there also something for CSS file, which can be fat also?

Thanks

Comment: why are you using **both** the regular and mobile jQuery?

Comment: @neal because you need them both

Comment: @mcgrailm, i do not believe that is true

Comment: @Neal well at least that what it shows in the [jquery mobile docpages](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/docs-pages.html)

Comment: @Rudu "In the 'head', references to jQuery, jQuery Mobile and the mobile theme CSS are all required to start things off:" but I haven't tried without it

Comment: Yeah I read the page you linked (after my I made my post)... it seems conclusive.  The project maintainers should consider a bit more clarity... (1) right up there on the front page (2) Create a *setup/install instructions* page in the docs (3) Specify in the downloads section that you also need to download jQuery.  'Anatomy of a Page' is hardly the first place you'd look for such information.

Answer (score 3):

**Insert this in your javascript:**

```
var LoadedScripts = new Array();

jQuery.getScript = function(url, callback, cache){
  if ($.inArray(url, LoadedScripts) > -1) {
    callback();
  }
  else {
     LoadedScripts.push(url);       
     jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      success: callback,
      dataType: "script",
      cache: cache
    });
  }
};
```

**How to use it:**

```
function YourFunction() {
   jQuery.getScript('path/to/your/script.js',function(){  
     // your code here - the script has loaded
   },true);
}
```

**change "true" to turn cache off and force reload of file (useful for css)**

```
function YourFunction() {
   jQuery.getScript('path/to/your/script.js',function(){  
     // your code here - the script has loaded
   },false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) can be used to shrink JS and CSS files, if you're downloading someone elses library/code, they usually provide a minified version so you'll see no savings over trying to min it again.  If you want to 'trim it down' to exclude parts of the library you aren't using, you may want to reconsider using a library in the first place and not just creating your own solutions for the pieces you need... but you may be surprised how useful the parts you're trying to exclude are.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load additional scripts on demand are you using the [minified jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js) and [jquery moblie](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js) files ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre><code>
  function require (src, callback) {
    if (!(src != null && (typeof src == 'string' || typeof src == 'object'))) return;
    var src = typeof src == 'string' ? [src] : src;
    var total = [];
    var loaded = [];
    var failed = [];
    var fn = function (e) {
      if (e.type == 'load') loaded.push(e.target.src);
      else failed.push(e.target.src);
      if ((loaded.length + failed.length) == total.length && typeof callback == 'function') callback(!!failed.length, loaded, failed);
    };
    var load = function (src) {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'application/javascript';
      s.src = src;
      s.addEventListener('error', fn, false);
      s.addEventListener('load', fn, false);
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
      return s.src;
    };
    for (var i in src) {
      var s = src[i].split(/[\s,]+/);
      for (var j in s) if (total.indexOf(s[j]) < 0) total.push(load(s[j]));
    }
  }

// Usage example:
require ('script1.js, script2.js, ...', function (hasError, loaded, failed) {
  console.log(arguments);
});

</code></pre>
```